# How to set all the rows of ng-repeat to be selected in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a smimple ng-repeat that displays user details. I am trying to set all the rows to be selected.

Currently I can manually click and select all the rows individually using following code:

```
 <tr  ng-repeat="room in classrooms" ng-class="{'selected': room.selected}" ng-click="select(room)">
```

in controller

```
$scope.select = function(item) {
    item.selected ? item.selected = false : item.selected = true;
}
```

and to get data from the selected rows I use following logic

```
$scope.getAllSelectedRows = function() 
{
  var x = $filter("filter")($scope.classrooms, 
    {
        selected: true
    }, true);

  console.log(x);
}
```

**UPDATED FROM @KADIMA RESPONSE**

```
$scope.toggleSelectAll = function()
{
   angular.forEach($scope.classrooms, function(room) {
       room.selected ? room.selected = false : room.selected = true;
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want here. Are you trying to make a way to select all the rooms at once, or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @Kadima , Yes that is exactly what I am trying to achieve. Select all rooms at once. Thank you

Comment: note : instead of using a function in the controller this shuld work : `ng-click="room.selected = !room.selected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a new function in your controller:

```
$scope.selectAll = function() {
    angular.forEach(classrooms, function(room) {
        room.selected = true
    }
}
```

And then you can create a button in your html to call this function.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select all data you got you can set selected property using angular.forEach() method.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

In your case:

```
angular.forEach(x, fuction(value) {
  value.selected = true;
}
```